# How to style a link in a paragraph

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

I searched everywhere for a solution but didn't find anything..

I have this code in an HTML5 page

```
<div>
    <p class="title_paragraph">
    <a id="title" href="http://www.milanochamberorchestra.com">Milano Chamber Orchestra</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

The CSS is

```
.title_paragraph {
    color: #f89938;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(230,160,55,0.6);
    font-family: 'Buda', cursive;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 46px;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#title:link {text-decoration:none;} 
#title:visited {text-decoration:none;} 
#title:hover {text-decoration:none;}   
#title:active {text-decoration:none;}
```

Why doesn't the link appear in the right color? It must be yellow/orange, not purple as it is!

Comment: it should be `.title_paragraph a` otherwise your link won't be styled

Comment: `a { color: inherit }` might be all you need, but that may have unintended consequences when you can no longer distinguish links from their surrounding text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
.title_paragraph a{
    color: #f89938;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(230,160,55,0.6);
    font-family: 'Buda', cursive;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 46px;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#title:link {text-decoration:none;} 
#title:visited {text-decoration:none;} 
#title:hover {text-decoration:none;}   
#title:active {text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: This is invalid `#title:link a` -1, edit your answer and I'll take back -1

Comment: Stil, invalid, read the question properly, you are missing something ;)

Comment: ^^^What it is that I am missing?

Comment: You are selecting element `a` which is inside `#title` but `#title` is assigned to `a` to it should be `#title:hover` and so on

Comment: ^^^didn't notice that. thanks for pointing it out. this is my `Aha!` moment of the day

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems your browser is displaying link style for "visited links" because you've already clicked on the link. You can also validate this by cleaning your browser cache. [Visited Links Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp) should solve your problem.